# Laravel 5.7 Auth::login($findUser, true) returns null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-socialite

I'm trying to login a user through laravel socialite. Everything is working fine but the user is not getting logged in!

I'm getting response from facebook, saving the response in the database and trying to login after that.

here is the code:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Laravel\Socialite\Two\InvalidStateException;
use Auth;
use Socialite;
use App\User;
use DB;
use Log;

public function handleProviderCallback($provider)
{
    $social = Socialite::driver($provider)->user();

    $findUser = User::where('email', $social->email)->first();

    if ($findUser) {
        // dd($findUser); **************** This returns information of the user who is trying to login through facebook
        // dd(Auth::login($findUser, true)); ***************** This line returns null
        if (Auth::login($findUser, true)) {
            // dd(Auth::loginUsingId($findUser->id, true));
            redirect()->route('dashboard');
        } else {
            return 'Error'; //**************** This get echoed on the screen
        }
    } else {
        $user = new User();

        $user->name = $social->name;
        $user->email = $social->email;
        $user->avatar = $social->avatar;
        $user->provider = $provider;
        $user->id = $social->id;
        $user->password = bcrypt('password');

        $user->save();
    }
    if (Auth::login($user)) {
        return redirect()->intended('/home');
    } else {
        return 'Error';
    }
}
```

Neither register, nor login is working.

Comment: use Log::info('some text'); to see what is happening. And check storage/logs/laravel.log to see the output

Comment: the log file is empty @ShehanDhaleesha

Comment: Can you show the `use` statements from the top of the class?

Comment: I have updated the question @RossWilson

Answer (score 0):

The `login()` method doesn't return anything so `if (Auth::login($findUser, true))` will never pass.

Also, it might be worth using the [firstOrCreate()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#other-creation-methods) to make your method smaller:

```
public function handleProviderCallback($provider)
{
    $social = Socialite::driver($provider)->user();

    User::unguard();

    $user = User::firstOrCreate([
        'email' => $social->email,
    ], [
        'id'       => $social->id,
        'name'     => $social->name,
        'avatar'   => $social->avatar,
        'provider' => $provider,
        'password' => bcrypt('password'),
    ]);

    auth()->login($user, true);

    return redirect()->intended('/home');
}
```

---

If you want to check if the User is signed in then you can use the `auth()->id()` method to retrieve the current authenticated user's id and then compare that to the `$user->id`:

```
if (auth()->id() !== $user->id) {
    return 'Error';
}
```

Obviously, if you prefer to use the `Auth` facade instead of the `auth()` helper function then you can use `Auth::id()` instead of `auth()->id()`

Comment: that didn't worked for me. I have installed laravel 5.6 and socialite 3.0 which works perfectly fine with my original code.

Comment: @UjjwalVerma That's weird...is it throwing an error or just not logging the user in?

Comment: it is not throwing any error but not letting user signin. `dd(Auth::login($findUser, true));` returns null though `dd($findUser);` returns an array of user details.

Comment: @UjjwalVerma Like I said in my answer, `Auth::login()` doesn't return anything so it's always going to evaluate to null. I have edited my question to show you how you could check to see if the user is signed in. The only thing that sounds weird to me is that `$findUser` is an array and not a `User` object.

Comment: Is it possible to authenticate a $user using Auth::login($user) without having the $user exist in the database? My users table exists in another Database/Laravel Project and using an API call I want to check if the user exists and if so I want to create a session in the Laravel project where I don't have my users stored.